# CXF: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider

Tags: java, osgi, cxf, aem, apache-felix

I'm trying to implement Apache CXF in CQ. I've generated proxy classes from WSDL using cxf-codegen-plugin. Now my `CxfServiceImpl.java` looks like below -

```
import net.webservicex.ConvertTemperatureSoap;
import net.webservicex.TemperatureUnit;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;

@Component(label = "CXF Service", immediate = true, metatype = true)
@Service(CxfService.class)
public class CxfServiceImpl implements CxfService {
    private ConvertTemperatureSoap convertTemperatureSoap;
    @Override
    public double convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(double valueToConvert) {
        return convertTemperatureSoap.convertTemp(
        valueToConvert, 
        TemperatureUnit.DEGREE_CELSIUS, 
        TemperatureUnit.DEGREE_FAHRENHEIT);
    }
    @Activate
    protected final void activate(final ComponentContext context) {
        convertTemperatureSoap =
        JaxWsClientFactory.create(
        ConvertTemperatureSoap.class,
        "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx");    
    }    
}
```

`JaxWsClientFactory.java` looks like -

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;
public class JaxWsClientFactory {
    public static <T> T create(Class<T> clazz, String portUrl) {
        ClassLoader oldClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(BusFactory.class.getClassLoader());
            JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
            factory.setServiceClass(clazz);
            factory.setAddress(portUrl);
            return (T) factory.create();
        } finally {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(oldClassLoader);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to create OSGI bundle and uploaded in Felix console. But when I try to activate bundle then I get error as below and bundle status is showing as Active.

```
24.02.2014 20:38:41.104 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1393254521079] POST /system/console/bundles/300 HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.cq.customer-bundle [com.adobe.cq.CxfServiceImpl] The activate method has thrown an exception (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2167)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1471)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.adobe.cq.JaxWsClientFactory.create(JaxWsClientFactory.java:12)
    at com.adobe.cq.CxfServiceImpl.activate(CxfServiceImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:236)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:37)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:613)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:496)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:149)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createImplementationObject(ImmediateComponentManager.java:251)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createComponent(ImmediateComponentManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$Unsatisfied.activate(AbstractComponentManager.java:1518)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ImmediateComponentHolder.enableComponents(ImmediateComponentHolder.java:328)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:158)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.<init>(BundleComponentActivator.java:113)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:261)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.bundleChanged(Activator.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:868)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:789)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:514)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4319)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1993)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:947)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:934)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BundlesServlet.doPost(BundlesServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:493)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:418)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider not found by com.adobe.cq.customer-bundle [300]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1499)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

pom.xml-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.adobe.cq.customer-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Export-Package>
                com.adobe.cq.*;version=${project.version}
                javax.xml.ws*;version=2.1;-split-package:=merge-first;-noimport:=true
            </Export-Package>
            <Private-Package>
                javax.jws,
                javax.jws.*,
                javax.wsdl,
                org.xml.*,
                org.apache.cxf,
                org.apache.cxf.*,
                javax.xml,
                org.apache.servicemix.specs.locator;-split-package:=merge-first
                javax.xml.transform.stax,
                javax.net.ssl,
                org.w3c.dom,
                org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.*,
                org.apache.ws.commons.schema.extensions.*,
                org.apache.ws.commons.schema.*,
                net.webservicex
            </Private-Package>
            <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>

            <Import-Package>
                org.osgi.framework,
                org.osgi.service.component.*,
                com.sun.msv.*;resolution:=optional,
                com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.*;resolution:=optional,
                com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.stax.*;resolution:=optional,
                net.sf.cglib.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.apache.aries.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.apache.axiom.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.apache.mina.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.apache.log4j.spi.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.apache.velocity.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.osgi.service.blueprint.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.junit.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.relaxng.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.slf4j.spi.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.springframework.*;resolution:=optional,
                javax.resource.*;resolution:=optional,
                javax.mail.*;resolution:=optional,
                javax.xml.ws.spi.http.*;resolution:=optional,
                junit.framework.*;resolution:=optional,
                com.sun.*;resolution:=optional,
                sun.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.apache.*;resolution:=optional,
                org.jvnet.*;resolution:=optional,
                javax.net.*,
                javax.xml.transform.stax,
                !*
            </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why are you specifying all those imports...?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I needed to roll back to Java 8 from Java 11 on this project.

I know this is not a long term solution, but it might be helpful for someone.

The more general solution would be to use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when CXF delegates to the JDK for the proxy generation. The problem there is that for all interfaces the proxy has to implement you can only set one classloader. Typically users do not have the BindpProvider in their classpath. SO cxf uses the bus classpath which looks in the bundle classpath first and then in the cxf classpath.

Which CXF version do you use? In older CXF versions this error was misleading sometimes. It was not only issues when the BindingProvider class was not found. It also happened when BindingProvider was loaded by cxf and the user bundle but from different classloaders.

The best way to avoid this problem is to import javax.xml.ws. So you have the highest chance you find the same interface as cxf. If the error then still happens you might have two bundles exporting the package.

In any case your bundle plugin instruction should not look as complicated as in your question. This only leads to problem. Just try.

```
<instructions>
  <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.adobe.cq.customer-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
  <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
  <Import-Package>
    javax.xml.ws,
    *
  </Import-Package>
</instructions>
```

Is there any special reason why you embed all your dependencies? CXF typically does work to well when used like this. Instead you can use the bundles from the CXF DOSGi multi bundle distro to install CXF into CQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **maven**, [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider%22) a quick link to the possible artifacts

Answer (score 0):

I'd say check your MANIFEST.MF first. It is complaining it's missing javax.xml.ws packages, so check if it is there in the Import-Package header.

If it isn't: Thats your problem, I guess you need to add it to your pom.xml.

If it *is* there, it's a bit more subtle.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have installed the JDK 1.6 (Java SE 6) I suggest you read the document [Using JAX-WS 2.x / Metro 1.x/2.0 with Java SE 6](https://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/Using_JAX_WS_2_x___Metro_1_x_2_0_with_Java_SE_6.html)

I solved a similar problem just by reading the attached document.